# clearing terminal while Nodemon is running?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, terminal, nodemon

Is there any way to clear terminal while **nodemon** is running?
I am using **Ubuntu 18.04**

Comment: try using `CTRL` + `L` key or using the `CTRL` + `K` key. I use a mac and `CTRL` + `K` works for me. However on a Unbuntu, the shortcut to clear the terminal is `CTRL` + `L`

Comment: CTRL+L works when nothing is running on terminal ie. nodemon isn't running

Comment: If you want to programmatically clear console, use this `console.clear()`

Answer (score 14):

Insert the following code into the `nodemon.json` file.

```js
{
    "events": {
      "start": "clear"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is what the nodemon events are for. You can include either a global or local `nodemon.json` file as per the following to do what you're after.

```
   {
      "events": {
        "start": "echo -ne '\\ec'"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

For macs, if `CTRL+K` doesn't work, try `command+K` (it does also work for react-scripts)

I'm posting an answer, because I can't yet comment posts, and for me `CTRL+K`, as was suggested, doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

use **nodemon config on package.json file**

add this code to package.json

```
  "nodemonConfig": {
    "events": {
      "start":"echo '--------------------\n'& clear || cls"      
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution

> On *Windows*: Press **'Ctrl + L'** ,
> then Press **Enter**.

> On *mac OS* and *Linux*: Press **'Command + K'** ,
> then Press **Return or Enter**.

It WORKED

Answer (score 2):

You can use `console.clear()` in your code while running nodemon .

No settings or files needed.
All OS works.

Answer (score 0):

When you type a `&` behind your command it will be executed in the background

`command &`

https://www.maketecheasier.com/run-bash-commands-background-linux/

Comment: How is this related to the OPs question?

Comment: @Sid110307 So you dont have to clear the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear the terminal you can use the command

```
tput reset
```

Is different to clear. The command clear print multiple empty lines, this command remove all lines before

Answer (score 0):

On Linux (tested on Ubuntu),

Press `Ctrl+L`, and then enter